# How to programatically change all backslashes to forwardslashes in netbeans 8.0

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

I have to work with code that consist of the following backslash structure:

```
require_once $doc_root . '\inc\db.php';
require_once $doc_root .'\inc\inventory_functions.php';
require_once $doc_root .'\inc\activity_functions.php';
```

I have 700 places in the whole project and I want to change these to forward slashes like these:

```
require_once $doc_root . '/inc/db.php';
require_once $doc_root .'/inc/inventory_functions.php';
require_once $doc_root .'/inc/activity_functions.php';
```

I probably need to use a regular expression and Netbeans Replace function to change it. However I'm not sure what should be the right regular expression syntax.

Comment: If you don't use `\n`, `\t`, `\r` type stuff then you can just replace them all, or am I missing something?

Comment: Using regular expressions with PHP: `preg_replace("/\\/", "/", "input string")`. Although you still have to change all the string constants in some way.

Comment: You should probably be using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR which will differ depending on the platform it's hosted on:

require_once join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($doc_root, 'inc', 'db.php');

Comment: I'm trying to repair the existing code. What would be the regex syntax to find  these lines and backslashes and replace with forward slashes?

Answer (score 1):

In **NetBeans** - go to `Edit` -> `Replace in Projects`, you'll get a popup window like below. Enter `\` in the `Containing Text` field, enter `/` into the `Replace With` field, choose `Scope` and `File Name Patterns` (I've chosen *.php):

[image: PopupWindow]

Then hit `Continue` - you'll get a `Search Results` tab, where you'll be able to un-select what you don't want to replace. Then hit the `Replace <...> matches`.

Comment: This is a great idea. How about if I want to find only the rows that start with 'require_once' and have backslashes? What would be the right syntax for that?

Comment: There is the `Match` pull-down menu in this window - you can choose `Regular Expression` and use Java patterns. Experimenting with these patterns is totally safe - NetBeans won't make any replacements until you hit the `Replace...` button

Comment: Sorry to say, using regular expressions here you'll be able only to *find* lines in your files. Replacement pattern should refer to parts of the line which has been found, and it looks like this window won't allow you to do that. But - the simplest approach (replacing \ by /) will still work with some manual control. Anyway - if you want more complex replacement, then you need Perl/Python etc.